# Where are the NgBootstrap v1.1.2 Docs?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to find out how display the current date on all our datepickers for v1.1.2 of NgBootstrap, but I can only find the docs for v3.x.

Anyone know where I can access the docs for v1.1.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [source code of the documentation](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.github.io/tree/cad1b2029dfd76c502efb2b443688b9fd6e9d93e) on the 13th April 2018 (date of the [`1.1.2` version](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/releases/tag/1.1.2)).

You can read the `app/components` folder or download the whole project for better readability.